# How can I force this image conversion into synchronous mode?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'd like to convert an image from .svg to .png. [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp) looks like a good choice and will do what I need, when called as:

```
sharp('input.svg').png().toFile('output.png');
```

Unfortunately, sharp's file interaction is completely asynchronous and does not fit into my completely synchronous environment at all. In other words, `.toFile` will write the file asynchronously and return a Promise. But my script needs `output.png` to be available in the next statement so it can be read and transformed further. I do not want to redesign my whole application only because this minor piece is asynchronous.

Is there a way to force the function into synchronous mode? I've looked at [sync-rpc](https://davidwells.io/snippets/forcing-async-functions-to-sync-in-node), but I cannot wrap my head around how I would employ it to cover this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--if `toFile` returns a promise why can't you just wait for it?

Comment: Sharp supports [callback](https://github.com/lovell/sharp#callback), is it synchronous enough for you?

Comment: @yqlim if a promise doesn't work for OP, why would a callback?